# Install grub on Windows 7 partition within Kali Linux

Tags: kali-linux, windows, grub2, grub, ntfs

I cant boot from the hard drive where my windows partition is located. I installed kali linux on my second drive and after that I couldnt boot into my Windows 7 drive. I tried to do it with boot menu but it wont work and in the grub menu windows 7 isnt listed.

My linux partition has the name sda1 and the Windows partition has the name sdb3.
If I run `grub-install /dev/sdb3` I get `Warning: Filesystem NTFS  doesnt support embedding.` and an error that embedding isnt possible but needed for installation on multiple drives.

I know there are things like grub4dos or grub2win but I cant find anything on how to install it within linux. Does anyone have experiences with that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a Windows issue

Comment: You are typing it wrong. **grub-install /dev/sdb && update-grub**

Comment: @roaima OP is trying to get Windows to boot and is looking at tools called "grub4dos" and "grub2win"... Doesn't sound like a Unix issue to me.

Comment: @roaima I thought I was being charitable.

Comment: @jasonwryan I am voting to "leave open" this question because **it is not a windows issue**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running `grub-install /dev/sdb3`, which is attempting to install a boot program in a partition. Grub quite rightly refuses to do that with NTFS.

Instead, install the grub bootloader to the disk, `grub-install /dev/sdb`. Or even `grub-install /dev/sda`.